# Facing errors in connecting openstack github repository?

Tags: linux, openstack

Am new to linux and openstack.
I was trying to install openstack in local Linux environment -Redhat. When I was running the below command I was getting below error

```
 [root@xyz123 apps]# git clone  https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack

 Cloning into 'devstack'....
  fatal: unable to access 'https://git.openstack.org. /openstack-dev/devstack': Failed to connect to 2001:4556:5666:334:be7. Network is unreachable
```

Tried the above URL with 'http.... But same error.
I also tried below URLs by googling.

```
   git clone  git://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
   Unable to connect to git.openstack.org: 
  git.openstack.org[0 : 100.138.234.128] :  errNo =No route to host
  git.openstack.org[1:2001.4334.6667.157.be67]: errNo=Network is unreachable


 git clone  https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git
 Unable to access 'https://github.com/openstack-dev/devstack.git/' : SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length
```

Note: git installed .version 1.8

Comment: "No route to host" "Network is unreachable"..

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems cloning that repo using either the "https:" or "git:" URLs.

Your problem could be / have been:

- A temporary problem with the Openstack git servers.
- A problem with the networking on the system where you are trying to run `clone`.
- Your access could be blocked blocked by your organization's firewall.
- Something like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_of_GitHub

Comment: It's a proxy issue. Once I kept git config --global http.proxy myproxyurl.it resolved.